# Galois group of $x^4 - t$ in $F_p(t)$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Compute the Galois group of $x^4 - t$ in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, distinguishing the cases $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

For $p \equiv 1$ we have $s \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $s^2 = - 1$ and we get $(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)(x-s\alpha)(x+s\alpha)$ where $\alpha^4 - t$, so the splitting field is $F_p(t)(\alpha)$ and the group should be $C_4$.

For $p\equiv 3$ however, we do not have $-1$ as a quadratic residue and I guess we get a factorization as above, but with $s \not\in \mathbb{F}_p(t)$. I suspect that the group should be $D_8$ but how to show it rigorously, i.e.: Why there is not a smaller splitting field than $\mathbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha, s)$ and that this degree is 8?  (Or perhaps there is a better way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x) = x^4 - t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and has degree $4$, if its splitting field has degree less than $8$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, it must have degree $4$.

Let $K = \mathbb{F}_p(t)(s)$, where $s^2 = -1$. A splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ must contain $K$, so if the splitting field is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, then it must be of degree $2$ over $K$. In other words, $f$ must have non-trivial factors in $K[x]$. However, $f$ is irreducible over $K$, so this is not possible. Hence, the splitting field is of degree $8$ and is as you have computed.

Comment: But how do we know that $f$ is irreducible over $K$? That's where we need $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, I guess :(

Comment: The factorization of $f$ into linear factors remains the same regardless of whether $s$ lies in the base field or not. You could check that there is no nontrivial factor of $f$ over $K$ by multiplying together the different bunches of factors, for instance.

Comment: I did not get that, where do we exactly use $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$?

Comment: OK I did it. It's easier to define s via s^2 + 1 = 0 and show that x^2 + 1 is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha$. Indeed $s$ can only be a constant (otherwise is a poly of $t, \alpha$ of non-zero degree) and now this is impossible when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DesmondMiles Some parts of your previous comment are a little unclear to me. When you say that it is easier to define $s$ via $s^2 + 1 = 0$, does it mean you were using a different definition of $s$ before? In my understanding, this is the only possible way to define $s$, as a root of the polynomial $x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)[x]$.

Comment: When you say that $s$ can only be a constant, I believe you have the right idea, but it needs to be expressed a bit more clearly. If I'm not wrong, you mean the following: the polynomial $x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha)[x]$ is also a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, and it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Hence, $\mathbb{F}_p(s) \cap \mathbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_p$. Please let me know if I'm interpreting your words correctly.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why you claim that "this is impossible" when $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. This leads me to believe that my interpretation of the statement "$s$ can only be a constant" is incorrect, so definitely your argument needs elaboration.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Lastly, I am assuming $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ throughout the answer, because you have already correctly dealt with the scenario $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ in the question details. I can edit the answer to clarify this, if needed.